# Disable Clipboard Mapping for RDP VPN Users

Tags: windows, vpn, rdp, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

On Windows, Terminal Services configuration allows you to enable or disable 'Clipboard Mapping' for RDP.

However, is it possible to selectively enable or disable this? i.e. If I want to enable clipboard mapping for people who are physically inside the corporate network, but want to disable it for people RDPing through VPN - is this possible?